# Classification of intractable/tractable satisfiability problem variants

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, satisfiability

Recently I found in a paper [1] a special symmetric version of SAT called the **2/2/4-SAT**. But there are many $\text{NP}$-complete variants out there, for example: **MONOTONE NAE-3SAT**, **MONOTONE 1-IN-3-SAT**, ...

Some other variants are tractable: $2$-$\text{SAT}$, Planar-NAE-$\text{SAT}$, ...

Are there survey papers (or web pages) that classify all the (weird) $\text{SAT}$ variants that have been proved to be $\text{NP}$-complete (or in $\text{P}$) ?

---

1. [Finding a shortest solution for the $N$x$N$ extension of the 15-Puzzle is intractable](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1986/AAAI86-027.pdf) by D. Ratner and M. Warmuth (1986)

Comment: @mrm: thanks, I didn't know Schaefer's paper (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=800133.804350)

Comment: I removed “post your favorite”, because this is [a textbook example of what not to ask on Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). (Yes, it works on [cstheory.se] to some extent, but that's a special case due to the highly atypical audience.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Classic, well-known results

As mentioned by Standa Zivny on the related question of CSTheory, [Which SAT problems are easy?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/which-sat-problems-are-easy), there's a well-known result by [Schaefer from 1978](https://dx.doi.org/10.1145/800133.804350) (quoting the answer of Zivny):

> If SAT is parametrised by a set of relations allowed in any instance, then there are only 6 tractable cases: 2-SAT (i.e. every clause is binary), Horn-SAT, dual-Horn-SAT, affine-SAT (solutions to linear equations in **GF**(2)), 0-valid (relations satisfied by the all-0 assignment) and 1-valid (relations satisfied by the all-1 assignment).

**Planar-3SAT** meaning the planar version of **3SAT** is known to be $\mathcal{NP}$-complete. See [D Lichtenstein, Planar formulae and their uses, 1981](http://link.aip.org/link/?SMJCAT/11/329/1). The non-planar version of 3SAT is of course the very well-known classic $\mathcal{NP}$-complete problem.

Not-All-Equal 3SAT (**NAE-3SAT**) is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete. However, the planar version of it is in $\mathcal{P}$ as shown by [Moret, Planar NAE3SAT is in P, 1988](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Emoret/nae3sat.ps).

## More recent and/or "weird" variants

## $k$-colourable Monotone NAE-3SAT

Here's a more exotic or weird variant, a decision problem called the **$k$-colourable Monotone NAE-3SAT**:

> Given a monotone CNF expression $\phi$ with exactly three distinct variables in each clause, such that the corresponding constraint graph $G(\phi)$ is k-colourable, is the expression $\phi$ not-all-equal satisfiable?

Here the corresponding constraint graph $G(\phi)$ is a simple undirected graph associated with $\phi$ as follows: Each variable of $\phi$ is a vertex in $G$, and two vertices have an edge between them iff they appear in some clause together.

For $k=4$ the problem is in $\mathcal{P}$. For $k=5$ however, it is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete. See [P Jain, On a variant of Monotone NAE-3SAT and the Triangle-Free Cut problem, 2010](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.3704.pdf).

## Linear CNF variants

While not perhaps being exotic or weird, some well-known variants, namely **NAE-SAT** (not-all-equal SAT) and **XSAT** (Exact SAT; *exactly one* literal in each clause to 1 and all other literals to 0), of the satisfiability problem have been investigated in the *linear* setting. Clauses of a linear formula pairwise have at most one variable in common. Interestingly, the complexity status does not follow from Schaefer's Theorem.

**NAE-SAT** and **XSAT** remain $\mathcal{NP}$-complete when restricted to linear formulas. Moreover, **NAE-SAT** and **XSAT** are still $\mathcal{NP}$-complete on formulas only containing clauses of length at least $k$, for each positive fixed integer $k \geq 3$. They are $\mathcal{NP}$-complete for monotone (no positive literals) linear formulas. However, **NAE-SAT** is polynomial-time decidable on exact linear formulas, where each pair of distinct clauses has exactly one variable in common.

Some further aspects regarding the complexity of **NAE-SAT** and **XSAT** under certain assumptions are probably still open. For more specifics, see for example [Porschen and Schmidt, On Some SAT-Variants over Linear Formulas, 2009](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-95891-8_41) and [Porschen et al., Complexity Results for Linear XSAT-Problems, 2010](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-14186-7_21).